# Alternatives to parental controls for Vista Business workgroup machine?

Tags: windows-vista, parental-controls, restrictions

How can I restrict access to the internet and execution of files on a Vista Business machine? The computer is part of a workgroup.

Answer (score 1):

You make make a separate user account for your children to use and install [**Windows Live Family Safety 2011**](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-family-safety?os=other).

Comment: Windows Live Family Safety 2011 looks good, but it is described as an enhancement to Parental Controls. As I understand it, parental controls are not an option in Business edition when connected through a workgroup. I've tried to enable Parental Controls via gpedit.msc, but Parental Controls fail to appear in Control Panel.

Comment: @user60935: Most of the Parental Controls were removed from Windows 7 Home Premium, along with all the Live stuff, so I would assume that you will still have most, if not all, of what you would have with Parental Controls in Vista Home Premium, as well as more, as this is what has replaced it.  You might as well try it and then see what else needs to be done, if anything.

Comment: I've tried, but Family Safety requires Parental Controls. Business doesn't support Parental Controls, there is plenty of ms documentation to confirm this. Several sites suggest registry hacks to enable Parental Controls. I have not been able to enable Parental Controls on this Vista Business. We are looking at third party software now.